# Can MAME save to cassette tape formats other than WAV?

Tags: emulation, cassette-tape, file-format, mame

MAME seems to be extremely unintuitive to use and extremely poorly documented. But it supports a ton of machines, some of which I haven't found other emulators for, so I've been persevering with it anyway.

One thing I haven't been able to figure out how to do so far is how to save to tape in any emulator file format other than WAV.

Even the fact that it's saving WAV took me a while to figure out because it can load the typical emulator tape formats that most emulators use.

For the Sinclair Spectrum and Timex 2068 I would normally use the `.tap` or `.tzx` formats and for TRS-80 model I would use the `.cas` format.

It loads all these formats perfectly fine. But when I use the same file extension to save, it seems to write not in that specified format, but only in WAV. I couldn't get them to load back in after saving them. Only when I used the Unix `file` command on the resulting files did I see they were all in WAV format.

Am I missing something where I should be able to specify what tape file format to use for saving or does it save only WAV by design?

Comment: You are basically asking how to use a modern piece of software. Have you tried asking on MAME support forums?

Comment: this MAME / MESS merge was not the smartest move

Comment: MAME only supports WAV files directly. [Castool](https://docs.mamedev.org/tools/castool.html) which is used to covert all the other tape formats to WAV files works only in the one direction.

Comment: @Brian: Thank you! I couldn't figure it out from the source code, Googling, or any of the forums. In fact I couldn't even log in to the forum to post a question after it confirmed that I had registered. I thought castool was just an extra commandline tool though rather than being actually used by the MAME program itself.